# Is there a Lorentz invariant action for a free multi-particle system?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, action, point-particles

I want to write down a Lorentz-invariant action of free multi-particle systems.

I know that a Lorentz-invariant action for each particle might be expressed as
$$
S[\vec{r}]=\int dt L(\vec{r}(t),\dot{\vec{r}}(t),t)=-\int dt\, m\sqrt{c^2-\Big(\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}\Big)^2}
$$
or
$$
S[r]=-\int d\sigma\, m\sqrt{\frac{dr^\mu(\sigma)}{d\sigma} \eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{dr^\nu(\sigma)}{d\sigma}}=-\int m c d\tau.
$$ In the second line, I parametrized the four vector $r^\mu$ including time $t$ by a parameter $\sigma$. The last expression assumes $\sigma$ coincides with the proper time $\tau$.

I tried to extend this analysis to (noninteracting) multi-particle systems. If we define
$$
r_i^\mu(\sigma)=\begin{pmatrix}
c t(\sigma)\\
x_i(\sigma)\\
y_i(\sigma)\\
z_i(\sigma))
\end{pmatrix}\quad...(*)
$$ ($i$ is the label distinguishing particles), we may write
$$
S[r]=-\int d\sigma\, \sum_{i=1}^Nm_i\sqrt{\frac{dr_i^\mu(\sigma)}{d\sigma} \eta_{\mu\nu} \frac{dr_i^\nu(\sigma)}{d\sigma}}=-\sum_{i=1}^N\int m_i c d\tau_i.
$$
To go to the last expression, $\sigma$ is chosen as the proper time for each particle. Indeed, this expression is in Landau's classical theory of fields textbook as Eq (27.2).

My problem is that $t$ in $(*)$ is common among all particles. Thus, the Lorentz transformation
$$
r_i'{}^\mu(\sigma)=\begin{pmatrix}
c t'(\sigma)\\
x_i'(\sigma)\\
y_i'(\sigma)\\
z_i'(\sigma))
\end{pmatrix}=\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}r_i^\nu(\sigma)
$$
for different $i$ gives mutually contradicting expressions for $t'$. This is why I couldn't verify the Lorentz invariance of the second last expression.
Should we introduce different $t'$ for each particle? (i.e., $t_i'$).

I looked up Goldstein Sec 7.10 but it does not really give me an answer.

Comment: Hint: Sum over particles.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question so that my confusion is clearer.

Comment: I think I found a solution. As $t$ was just an integration valuable, I could have set $t\to t_i$ from the begging, and then it is natural to write $t_i'$ after Lorentz transformation. Thanks to different $t_i$ and $t_i'$ for each particle, there is no contradiction anymore. Thanks again for your help.